# Deploy Spark-Java (Gradle, Maven) application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat, intellij-idea, spark-java

I am having trouble connecting to the endpoints of my java application deployed to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. The application handles a number of POST requests and is intended to serve a mobile application, so the server itself does not have any static files. I used the Spark Java framework, which finds the endpoints correctly when I test on Localhost, but not on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

I can deploy the Exploded war onto EB (running Tomcat Web server), yet all requests that I send return a 404 Error: Resource not Found. Spark java runs on the embedded Jetty server, so to run on Tomcat, I did as suggested in their documentation (http://sparkjava.com/documentation#other-web-server): I have implemented the SparkApplication interface, moving all endpoints from main() to init() and I added the suggested code to the web.xml file.

The .war uploaded contains META-INF with web.xml, lib (with the gradle libraries), and classes (with my compiled output). Again, no static files.

More details:

I use the Elastic Beanstalk IntelliJ (Ultimate) plugin to deploy and at this point I tested that this is no different from deploying a .war directly on the EB dashboard. I have opened to all ports and connections in security settings to discard any connectivity issue. I believe this is just a matter of the servlet not mapping the urls. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Run it as a war on local box to make sure you have the wiring right.  I have done this recently - Spark Java on Beanstalk, but I think I deployed it as a jar.  Beanstalk supports just straight java jar (fronts it with nginx).  I think when I deployed as a jar, I did have to do something to specify the listening port of 4567 that Spark Java uses by default.

I have run Spark Java as a war in Tomcat as well, but I don't think on AWS - I believe in that case I deployed as a jar.

Comment: Ok, let me try the .jar

Comment: It's an option with AWS and more natural for Spark Java.  I have run Spark under Tomcat as a war though - one thing to keep in mind is as a war tomcat will give a context that is the war name that you have to add to URL before your REST api paths.  So if you have blah.war on 8090, localhost:8090/blah/myrestpath, not localhost:8090/myrestpath.

Comment: Thank you! It turned out to be a port issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I had code inside the main class that was changing the port. While this was necessary to run on the local environment, it conflicted with AWS, which assigns the port automatically.